# run testng methods in parallel for webdriver

Tags: testng

The script has methods=parallel. But it executes only one method any given time and gives error for another.

testng script:

```
<suite name="test suite" verbose="1" parallel="methods" thread-count="3">

<test name="test on FF">
<parameter name="platform" value="local" />
<parameter name="browser" value="firefox" />
<parameter name="version" value="13" />
<parameter name="login" value="test" />
<classes>
  <class name="com.auto.tests.TitlesTests" >
    <methods>
        <include name="testCreateNewTitle" />
        <exclude name="testCreateNewTitlesFolder" />
        <include name="testCreateNewTitlesUsingAuto" />
    </methods>
  </class>
  </classes>
```

The BeforeClass, BeforeMethod, BeforeSuite are in one script and the @Test selenium webdriver tests are in another script.

```
Class A

@BeforeSuite
public void beforeSuite() throws Exception {
    log.info("BeforeSuite");
}

    @BeforeTest
public void beforeTest() throws Exception{

        setupBrowser("Default test");
    }
}

    @BeforeClass
public void beforeClass() throws Exception {
    if(loginMethod.equalsIgnoreCase("class")){
        setupBrowser(this.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
}

    @BeforeMethod
public void beforeMethod(Method method) throws Exception {
    log.info("BeforeMethod");
    if(loginMethod.equalsIgnoreCase("method")){
        setupBrowser(method.getName());
    }
}

class B extends A {

 @Test
public void testCreateNewtitle(){
                log.info("Create new title test case1 starts");
        log.info("Create folder1 worked");
        }

@Test
public void testCreateNewTitlesUsingAuto(){
                log.info("Create new title test case2 starts");
        log.info("Create folder2 worked");
        }
```

}

```
testng output
[main] 0      INFO  - BeforeSuite
[main] 14     INFO  - BeforeTest
[main] 16562  INFO  - Browser = firefox, Version = 13, Platform = local
[main] 22953  INFO  - Authenticated. HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
[main] 22954  INFO  - 
[pool-1-thread-1] 31981  INFO  - BeforeClass
[pool-1-thread-2] 31988  INFO  - BeforeMethod
[pool-1-thread-1] 31988  INFO  - BeforeMethod
[pool-1-thread-1] 32005  INFO  - Create new title test case1 starts
[pool-1-thread-2] 32011  INFO  - Create new title test case2 starts
[pool-1-thread-2] 32079  ERROR - 
[pool-1-thread-2] 32090  INFO  - AfterMethod
[pool-1-thread-1] 32091  INFO  - Create folder1  worked
[pool-1-thread-1] 59100  INFO  - AfterMethod
[pool-1-thread-1] 59101  INFO  - AfterClass
[main] 59103  INFO  - AfterTest
[main] 59778  INFO  - AfterSuite

java.lang.AssertionError: null
at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:89)
at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:96)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at               org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:715)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:907)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1237)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you also paste the code of log.info

Comment: In testng output block above - INFO is log.info output